# Get value of field by calculation based on compression of 2 Combo Box... if used as need to add more formula

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to get the field value by formula by comparing 2 combo boxes. I am getting the 1st part right but the 2nd part.

```
Private Sub Convert_Rate_Unit_AfterUpdate()
    If [Convert_Rate_Unit] = [Rate_Per_Unit] Then
        [ConvertRate] = [Rate]
        If [Convert_Rate_Unit] <> [Rate_Per_Unit] Then
            [ConvertRate] = [Rate / 1000]
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Your second if-clause shouldn't be inside the fist since you can't have them be the same _and_ different. An If... Else would've sufficed here as @Mathias Z showed in his answer.

Comment: If you indent your code properly (like you always should) the issue should be obvious

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the brackets you've got wrong:

```vb
Private Sub Convert_Rate_Unit_AfterUpdate()

    If [Convert_Rate_Unit] = [Rate_Per_Unit] Then
        [ConvertRate] = [Rate]
    Else
        [ConvertRate] = [Rate] / 1000
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Indentation is important... try, next time to specify your question better by adding the error message you get and so on. Rename your controls according the suggestion bellow and everything should work :

```
Private Sub cboConvertedUnitRate_AfterUpdate()

    Me.txtConvertRate = GetUnitRate

End Sub

Private Function GetUnitRate() As Double
    
    Dim dblRate As Double
    Dim dblReturnValue As Double
    '
    If Not IsNull(Me.txtRate) Then
        dblRate = Me.txtRate
    Else
        Call MsgBox("Please enter a value in the rate field", vbOKOnly)
        dblRate = 0
    End If
    '
    If Not IsNull(Me.cboConvertedUnitRate) And Not IsNull(Me.cboUnitRate) Then
       '
       If (Me.cboConvertedUnitRate) = (Me.cboUnitRate) Then
            '
            dblReturnValue = dblRate
            '
       Else
            '
            dblReturnValue = Round(dblRate / 100, 2)
            '
       End If
    '
    Else
        Call MsgBox("Please select a value in the combo boxes", vbOKOnly)
    End If
    
    GetUnitRate = dblReturnValue
        
End Function
```